# cassandra-stress returns "Failed to connect over JMX; not collecting these stats"

Tags: nosql, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I took the DS210 course offered by Datastax and prepared a cluster of almost the same configuration by myself. I edited the /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh file in Exercise 2.3, but I still got "Failed to connect over JMX; not collecting these statscassandra-stress" error message; I get "not collecting these stats" and cassandra-stress does not work properly.
When I look at the jconsole, the graph is working, so it seems to be collecting information. What should I change?
I am running on DSE 6.8.

cassandra-stress
cassandra-stress user profile=/home/cassandra01/ubuntu/stress/TestProfileEdited.yaml ops(insert=1,user_by_email=1) -node  -port jmx="7199"

```
command:
  Type: user
  Count: -1
  No Warmup: false
  Consistency Level: LOCAL_ONE
  Target Uncertainty: 0.020
  Minimum Uncertainty Measurements: 30
  Maximum Uncertainty Measurements: 200
  Command Ratios: {insert=1.0, user_by_email=1.0}
  Command Clustering Distribution: clustering=gaussian(1..10)
  Profile File(s): /home/cassandra03/ubuntu/stress/TestProfileEdited.yaml
Rate:
  Auto: true
  Min Threads: 4
  Max Threads: 1000
Population:
  Distribution: Gaussian:  min=1,max=1000000,mean=500000.500000,stdev=166666.500000
  Order: ARBITRARY
  Wrap: false
Insert:
  Revisits: Uniform:  min=1,max=1000000
  Visits: Fixed:  key=1
  Row Population Ratio: Ratio: divisor=1.000000;delegate=Fixed:  key=1
  Batch Type: not batching
Errors:
  Ignore: false
  Tries: 10
Log:
  No Summary: false
  No Settings: false
  No Progress: false
  Show Queries: false
  Query Log File: null
  File: null
  Interval Millis: 1000
  Level: NORMAL
Mode:
  API: JAVA_DRIVER_NATIVE
  Connection Style: CQL_PREPARED
  CQL Version: CQL3
  Protocol Version: DSE_V2
  Username: null
  Password: null
  Auth Provide Class: null
  Max Pending Per Connection: 128
  Connections Per Host: 8
  Compression: NONE
Node:
  Nodes: [192.168.56.124]
  Is White List: false
  Datacenter: null
Schema:
  Keyspace: null
  Replication Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy
  Replication Strategy Options: {replication_factor=1}
  Table Compression: null
  Table Compaction Strategy: null
  Table Compaction Strategy Options: {}
Transport:
  truststore=null; truststore-type=null; truststore-password=null; keystore=null; keystore-type=null; keystore-password=null; ssl-protocol=TLS; ssl-alg=SunX509; ssl-ciphers=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA; 
Port:
  Native Port: 9042
  JMX Port: 7199
Send To Daemon:
  *not set*
Graph:
  File: null
  Revision: unknown
  Title: null
  Operation: USER
TokenRange:
  Wrap: true
  Split Factor: 1

******************** Profile(s) ********************
  Keyspace Name: dse_stress
  Keyspace CQL: 
***
CREATE KEYSPACE dse_stress WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'};
***

  Table Name: user_by_email
  Table CQL: 
***
CREATE TABLE user_by_email (
  email TEXT,
  password TEXT,
  user_id UUID,
  PRIMARY KEY ((email))
)
***

  Extra Schema Definitions: null
  Generator Configs:
    password: Size: Exponential:  min=8,max=30,mean=14.234680;Identity: Uniform:  min=1,max=1000000;
    email: Size: Gaussian:  min=8,max=30,mean=19.000000,stdev=3.666667;Identity: Exponential:  min=1,max=1000000,mean=144764.693015;
    user_id: Size: Fixed:  key=4;Identity: Uniform:  min=1,max=1000000;
  Query Definitions:
    get_user: CQL:select * from user_by_email where email = ?;Fields:samerow;
  Token Range Queries:
  Insert Settings:
    partitions: fixed(1)
    batchtype: UNLOGGED
    select: fixed(1)/1
Connected to cluster: Test Cluster, max pending requests per connection 128, max connections per host 8
Datacenter: dc1; Host: /192.168.xx.xxx; Rack: rack1
Datacenter: dc1; Host: /192.168.xx.xxx; Rack: rack1
Datacenter: dc2; Host: /192.168.xx.xxx; Rack: rack1
Created schema. Sleeping 1s for propagation.
Insert Statement:
  UPDATE user_by_email SET password = ?,user_id = ? WHERE email = ?
Generating batches with [1..1] partitions and [1..100] rows (of [1..1] total rows in the partitions)

Sleeping 2s...
Warming up insert with 0 iterations...
Failed to connect over JMX; not collecting these stats
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your cassandra-env.sh file.  Remote JMX needs to be enabled for that to work.

Look for the `LOCAL_JMX` variable, and make sure that’s getting set to something other than ”yes.”

Once that’s done, cassandra-stress should be able to pull metrics w/JMX.